# showing data from tableview in a text field objective C/iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

can't for the life of me figure this out.

so I'm creating a contact list app, very similar to the one that comes with iOS7.

- a user creates a name with the GUI on a detail view controller.
- user goes back to the main contact list page (master view controller)
- user taps on the name/contact they just created
- brings them back to the view controller, but it shows what they had entered into the text fields.

User starts with this screen: 
[image]
User hits the add contact button, adds in the user data here which brings them back to the first screen:[image]

Next, they are brought to the first screen and are able to tap on the contact they've added and should bring up all the details entered (firstname,lastname,phone number etc):

here's my code in my master view controller:

```
- (void) detailViewControllerWillDissapear: (DetailViewController *) dvc {
    NSLog(@"test");
    DirectoryEntry *person = [[DirectoryEntry alloc] init];

    person.firstName = dvc.txtFirstName.text;
    person.lastName = dvc.txtLastName.text;
    person.phoneNumber = dvc.txtPhoneNumber.text;
    person.address = dvc.txtAddress.text;

    [self.entries addObject:person];

    NSLog(@"index is %@", person.firstName);
    NSLog(@"count of array %lu", (unsigned long)self.entries.count);

    dvc.holdData = person;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

here's my segue:

```
#pragma mark - segue
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    //DirectoryEntry *person = [[DirectoryEntry alloc] init];

    DetailViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    dvc.delegate = self;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:(@"tappedData")]) {
        NSLog(@"what is the person class have %@", dvc.holdData);
        // NSLog(@"dvc.holdData = %@", person.firstName);
    }
}
```

so I've created the public variable holdData which is meant to hold all the data which was entered from the array into the Person class. but whenever I add it, just comes up with a Null value. I am able to access the variables i.e. holdData.firstName, but just everything is null.

any ideas? really confused, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `dvc` that you have in `prepareForSegue` is almost certainly not the same object that you had in the `detailViewControllerWillDissapear` method.  (Try printing their addresses to prove that for yourself.)  That means that either your main controller should save the `Person` data and provide it during the segue or you could create a separate data model that each `DetailViewController` would use directly.

Comment: So I've added in the main view controller viewdidLoad

dvc.holdData = person;

and it prints out only the first object, but not in any other method? It's a public variable. any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: I don't even know why a `DetailViewController` would exist when you're in `viewDidLoad` for the main controller.  Like I said, "provide it [i.e. the Person] during the segue".

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to iOS, not sure what you mean provide it? do you mean create another instance of person?

Comment: I just mean to pass it to the controller.  In `prepareForSegue` find the person in `self.entries` that matches the `sender` and then use something like `dvc.holdData = person`.